# Script no Firestore (Firebase) não chega no update

Tags: node.js, firebase, post

Estou tendo problemas com o código abaixo. O código chega até o postbackRef.add e adiciona as informações no banco, mas depois disso ele não entra no transactionsRef.where para realizar o update logo abaixo em transactionUpdate.update. O que pode ser?

```
pagarme.post("/retornoPagarme", function (req, res) {
var transactionsRef = db.collection('transactions');
var postbackRef = db.collection('postback_return');

var setPostback = postbackRef.add({
    return: req.body
}).then((ref) => {
    var transactionSnapShot = transactionsRef.where('id_pagarme', '==', req.body.id).get();
    let values = null;
    transactionSnapShot.forEach(doc => {
        values = doc.data();
    });
    var transactionUpdate = transactionsRef.doc(values.id);
    transactionUpdate.update({
        status_pagarme: req.body.current_status,
        status: req.body.current_status
    })

    postbackRef.doc(ref.id).set({ status: req.body.current_status });

    return res.status(200);
});

return res.status(200);

});
```

Comment: Você já tentou fazer um `console.log` antes da linha `var transactionSnapshot...`? A consola não mostra nenhum erro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido! Era um problema de tipagem de variáveis...

```
var transactionSnapShot = transactionsRef.where('id_pagarme', '==', Number(req.body.id)).get();
```